# Visual Studio break all in debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a solution, both client and server running, with many projects, the front end is Silverlight in my solution. 
As the code is running I hit break all and expect to stop in the currently running line of code. Instead I receive the "No Source Available, There is no source code available for the current location" message.
What could be the solution for this?
Note that it happens whenever I hit break all, no matter which part is being executed. standard breakpoints do stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the standard behavior... Remember that behind the scenes you have the framework dlls (ntdll.dll / windowsbase.dll / presentationframework.dll etc.)  doing their magic (listening to message pumps, working with the OS etc.)...

So most of the time when you "Break All", you have a very good chance of falling into one of them.
You can open the `Call Stack` window and see exactly where you are (you might need to right-click and "`Show External Code`")... and Sometimes you might also see your specific method calls in there...

Putting breakpoints in *your* code and stopping in them is usually the correct method to stop in methods that are relevant to your specific application.

Comment: In a previosu job, I used "Break All" almost daily to do what the OP was hoping for and what you must describing as non-standard behavior.  Basically, you could initiate the Break All mode and then, as soon as you interacted with your application in a way that caused execution to go through your code (i.e. not the framework, and not some third party DLL) it would pause.  It was, in effect, like placing a break point on every single line of your own code and then starting the debugger.

Now I'm in a new job and the behavior is like OP describes.  How do I get it back to what I once had?