# Attempting to use debug tools in Visual Studio 2019 results in "Source Not Available" screen

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I'm learning C++ and part of that is learning how to debug. My code works as written, but I want to be able to step through it line by line. I can start debugging just fine, but I can't use the debugging tools "Show next statement", "Step into", or "Step over". They all show a screen that says "Source not available; Source information is missing from the debug information for this module." I don't know what source is missing. There's only one file in this program. I've looked online and found that maybe some symbol files are missing. So I went into Options > Debugging > Symbols and clicked "Load all symbols." Obviously this didn't resolve the issue. Again, I'm pretty sure *my* code isn't the problem, it all works otherwise.

Code for reference:

```
#include <iostream>

int getUserInput() {
    std::cout << "\nEnter an integer: ";
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}

std::string getOperator() {
    std::cout << "\nEnter an operator: ";
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}

int calculateResult(int x, std::string sign, int y) {
    if (sign == "*") {
        return x * y;
    }
    else if(sign == "/"){
        return x / y;
    }
    else if (sign == "-") {
        return x - y;
    }
    else if (sign == "+") {
        return x + y;
    }
}

void displayResult(int x, std::string y, int z, int r) {
    std::cout << x << y << z << " = " << r;
}

int main() {
    int num1{ getUserInput() };
    std::string sign(getOperator());
    int num2{ getUserInput() };
    int result{ calculateResult(num1, sign, num2 ) };
    displayResult(num1, sign, num2, result);
}
```

Again, I know there's no need to debug this code, it's more about knowing how to use the tools. Since I can't use the tools, I can't learn how to use them.

Update 1: It seems that if I start debugging by clicking "step into" from the debug menu, I can use the tools mentioned before. This is some strange behavior.

Comment: Depending on your project type and debugging options, debugger might want to step into non user code (for ex. code that is executed before main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm these options on your side:

- Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Debug Information format, the `Program Database for Edit And Continue (/ZI)` has been selected
- In visual studio, Menu Debug > Options > General, the `Enable Just My code` has been enabled

After that, you can clean > build your project and set some breakpoints, then debug, if the breakpoint is hit, try to re-use those tools.

Comment: So I think I was using the tools in the wrong order. If I have it stop at my cursor, hit a breakpoint, or just press f11 I can use the tools. The only instance in which I can't is if I start the program, then press the "break all" button. If that's normal behavior, I'm glad I learned it. If not, uh oh?

Comment: @MacKinzee, "Break all" is not a right operation to step-by-step debug. This thread has explained it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15221306/14324452